# Communication on 2 ports between 2 Android devices using WiFi Direct

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am creating an application that will monitor movements in a particular Android device (client) and report such instances to another Android device (server). Also, under specific conditions, the client will take a picture and transmit the image to the server.

I am using WiFi direct to setup the connection between the two devices. After that I am using socket connections as explained in the WiFi Direct Demo. I am using port 8988 to send the motion sensor events and I am using port 8987 to send the images capture.

On the server side, I am using two different instances of the same Async Task with serversocket connecting to different ports to listen for the incoming messages. Everything works fine as long as only the motion sensor events are being sent across. The first image capture is also being sent/received correctly. However, after that the server doesn't receive any additional messages. I tried having two different Async Task classes to avoid having two instances of the same class but that didn't work as well. I also tried having one as an Async Task and another as an Intent Service but even that doesn't work.

This is IntentService I am using to send the messages across to the server.

```
public class MessageSender extends IntentService {

    public static final String EXTRAS_TIMEOUT = "timeout";
    public static final String EXTRAS_ADDRESS = "go_host";
    public static final String EXTRAS_PORT = "go_port";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DATA = "data";

    private Handler handler;

    public MessageSender(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public MessageSender() {
        super("MessageTransferService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_ADDRESS);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_PORT);
            byte[] data = intent.getExtras().getByteArray(EXTRAS_DATA);
            int timeout = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_TIMEOUT);
            try {
                socket.bind(null);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), timeout);
                OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                stream.write(data);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception has occurred: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                            /*handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Connection closed now..",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });*/
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is Async Task on the server that starts listeners on two ports (8987 and 8988) to receiver the information of motion sensor events and images.

```
public class MessageReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    private int port;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public MessageReceiver(Context context, int port) {
        this.context = context;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            String returnString = "";
            if (port == MainActivity.PORT_SENSOR_COMM) {
               // do something
            } else if (port == MainActivity.PORT_IMAGE_COMM) {
                //do something
            }
            serverSocket.close();
            return returnString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception Occurred:" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        boolean startNewTask = true;
        if (port == MainActivity.PORT_SENSOR_COMM) {
            //do something
        } else if (port == MainActivity.PORT_IMAGE_COMM) {
            //do something
        }
        //doing this to start listening for new messages again
        new MessageReceiver(context, port).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

}
```

I am now wondering whether Android WiFiDirect allows parallel communication between two devices on different ports. Searched the docs but could'nt find much help. What I am doing wrong? What is the correct method to accomplish what I am trying to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Comment: yes , its possible to have parallel communication using wifi-direct

Comment: You close the server socket and the async tasks ends. So how should it receive the following message or image?

Comment: I see now that in onPostExecute you start a new task. Ok. But where can we see that clients connect again?

Comment: That happens from the listeners - Sensor and SurfaceTexture. Basically the MessageSender service is invoked again when there is an event.

Comment: If a new listener is created before the old is ready and the new client tries to connect it connects maybe to the old server. The old server gets killed and the new one waits...

Comment: I wonder why you every time kil your server socket and task. Just make a while loop in doInBackground to listen for the next client or message or image.

Comment: That would loop the AsyncTask forever which I understand is not recommended. Also, I have tried the while loop in an intentservice with the same issue.

Comment: AsynkTask is for short works under 2,3 secs. so I think u need a service for that. let me know what u thinking now.

Comment: @David, I have tried the service also. Faced the same issue.